# What Relational Database To Use With Groovy

Tags: groovy, relational-database

I am working my way through Groovy in Action.  Chapter 10 on database programming recommends using the Hypersonic database system, this now seems to have changed to the Hyper SQL Database.

Is this a good database to work with or should I consider something else?

Answer (score 2):

HSQL is fine, works very well. You can, however, use your choice of any of the [databases supported by Hibernate](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SupportedDatabases2#).

Comment: Not that Hibernate doesn't support most db's you can think of, but Hibernate isn't a limiting factor, as he's not specifying Grails.  Anything with a JDBC driver should be peachy.

Comment: @BrianHenry Yup, my bad - I saw "Groovy in Action" and read it as "Grails in Action". Indeed, anything with a decent JDBC driver should be fine.